# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 tabs page shifts when link clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter-Bootstrap 3.0

Tabs specifically, here is the link:

[Twitter-Bootstrap Link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)

The tabs are enclosed in a div with width: 100%; which are stacked onto of each other for a billboard type website. If the billboard with the tabs is present, and a tab is clicked when the tab navigation is in the middle of the screen, the tab nav then jumps to the top of the screen and renders the tab content. I would like to not have any shift in the page when the details are shown. If the content runs below the bottom window then the user should continue to scroll to view it.

```
<div id="programs" class='billboard'>
  <div class="billboard-wrapper">
    <h1>PROGRAMS HERE</h1>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class='tab-content tab-cell'>
      <div class='tab-pane active' id='tab1'>
        hello tab one
      </div>
      <div class='tab-pane active' id='tab2'>
        hello tab two
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mind creating an example reproducing the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/343yw4vo/

Comment: Why do you have both tab panes marked"active"?

Comment: Copy paste error that WAS in the code. Thanks, that was the issue.